# How to select to the end of line

Tags: regex, grep, textwrangler

I am trying to clean up a text file.
Every line has a tab in the middle somewhere.
I want to delete everything including that tab to the end of that each line. This will give me just the text before the tab in each line.

I am struggling with grep syntax in TextWrangler search to achieve this.

Comment: does your editor have regex supported replace function?

Comment: Does this work? `\t.*$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\t.*$` to select everything from a tab (inclusive) to the end of a line. `\t` represents a tab and `$` represents end of line.